# Export google doc to PNG and send it on email script

Tags: google-apps-script, export, png

I need a simple way to export - saveAs or getAs, a google document to PNG or JPG and send it on email. 
I was able to get it as pdf with 'application/pdf' with this: [Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)

But wasn't able to use 'image/png' with the same code. The code I use to get .pdf is:

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById("docID").getAs("application/pdf");
```

Should I change the code to function for PNG?

Comment: What exactly happens if you do `getAs("image/png")`?

Comment: nothing happens. the script stops.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype) says:

> For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

A Google Document is not an image, so the only type offered is PDF.

What you *can* do is to save any *images* embedded in a document as PNG, like this.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('...');
var image = doc.getBody().getImages()[0];   // first image in document
var file = DriveApp.createFile(image.getBlob().setName('my image.png'));
```

Comment: and what about save as image a pdf?